# How to put values entered in a prompt into a table

Tags: sas, enterprise

I created a prompt called &CPF where I enter several values, I would like to put all the values entered in a table.
[Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGhJK.png)

I've tried a few things but nothing worked.

data TESTE;
set original (keep=&TESTE);
run;

Would anyone know how to do this?

Thanks in advice

Answer (score 1):

When you have a multi-valued prompt, each value is stored in its own macro variable. In your case, we'll suppose that your prompt is named `TESTE`. You want to keep only the variables that the user enters.

Suppose we're going to run this on sashelp.cars. We want to keep the variables Make, Model, and Horsepower. Create a test program with a prompt named TESTE that runs the following code:

`%put _USER_;`

This displays all user-defined macro variables. Let's run the program with the prompt and check the log.

[image]

You will see the following macro variables:

```
GLOBAL TESTE Make
GLOBAL TESTE0 3
GLOBAL TESTE1 Make
GLOBAL TESTE2 Model
GLOBAL TESTE3 Horsepower
GLOBAL TESTE_COUNT 3
```

`TESTE1-TEST3` holds each invidiual value, and `TESTE_COUNT` gives you the total count of macro varibles. You can use this to loop through and get each value. Note that if you only have one input, only `&TESTE` will be created rather than numbered values. We can create a loop that starts at 2 to account for this.

```
%macro teste;
    data teste;
        set sashelp.cars(keep=&teste 
                              %do i = 2 %to &teste_count.;
                                  &&teste&i
                              %end;
                        );
    run;
%mend;
%teste;
```

You can resolve all of these macro variables into a space-separated list by creating a macro which returns it when you specify the prompt name.

```
%macro get_prompt_values(name);
    %let list=&&&name.;

    %do i = 2 %to &&&name._count;
        %let list = &list &&&name.&i;
    %end;
    
    &list
%mend;

data teste;
    set sashelp.cars(keep=%get_prompt_values(teste));
run;
```

Comment: I think you need a switch in your macro based on TESTE_COUNT.  If the user selects only one option, I don't think the macro variable TESTE1 is created, so you have to use TESTE.

Comment: Yep, absolutely right. Updated the code for this.

Comment: Well that was a better fix than my suggestion of adding a switch. : )